# MVVM Dynamic Menu UI from binding with ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, menu

I am working with a team on LoB application. We would like to have a dynamic `Menu` control, which creates the menu based on the logged in user profile. In previous development scenarios (namely ASP.NET) we use to iterate through data which describes collection and generate `MenuItem` dynamically. In MVVM how would I do this? Can I separate XAML view from ViewModel which describes menu elements?

**Solution:**

With inputs from commentators I were able to bind `Menu` dynamically with the data from ViewModel. This [article](http://uicraftsman.com/blog/2008/11/26/building-a-databound-wpf-menu-using-a-hierarchicaldatatemplate/) was of great help too.

XAML:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:Menu}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=MenuText}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

[...]

<Menu Height="21" Margin="0" Name="mainMenu" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TopMenuItems}">
    <Menu.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Wpf.Modules;component/Images/MenuBg.jpg" />
    </Menu.Background>
</Menu>
```

`Menu` data class:

```
public class Menu : ViewModelBase
{
    public Menu()
    {
        IsEnabled = true;
        Children = new List<Menu>();
    }

    #region [ Menu Properties ]

    private bool _isEnabled;
    private string _menuText;
    private ICommand _command;
    private IList<Menu> _children;

    public string MenuText
    {
        get { return _menuText; }
        set
        {
            _menuText = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("MenuText");
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            _isEnabled = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
        }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
        set
        {
            _command = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("Command");
        }
    }

    public IList<Menu> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set
        {
            _children = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: After spending some time in Google I found HierarchicalDataTemplate could be helpful in dynamic menu creation, and yet separate "concerns" with MVVM pattern. I don't have any code samples yet :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel
{
    public MenuItemViewModel()
    {
        this.MenuItems = new List<MenuItemViewModel>();
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public IList<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems { get; private set; }
}
```

Assume that your DataContext has a property called MenuItems which is a list of MenuItemViewModel. Something like this should work, then:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:MenuItemViewModel}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Text}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}" />
        <Grid />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi with this I could bind my class to Menu, but how could I structure them hierarchically? Each menu item is having a parentId, those with null parentId are root menu elements and I want to organize rest menu under them. Is there any other resource on HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Thanks

Comment: And also how could I assign style from XAML to MenuItem as they are not explicitly defined in the XAML?

Comment: Styles to MenuItem can be assigned using ItemContainerStyle property of Menu.

Comment: I would like this answer better if it included how to bind the commands to the menu!

Comment: What about `Separator` ? Suppose we have a `Separator` model class, how can we build the menu with separators?

Comment: I'm new to learning WPF and was able to get this to work but I think the last few comments are all hinting at what I'm wondering...  Is there not a predefined MenuItem Model defined in the .NET framework somewhere so my view model can be simple?

Answer (score 14):

This should get you where you are going

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowsUI.Views.Default.MenuView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:WindowsUI.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
    </Style>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
        DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MenuItemViewModel}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"/>
```

Note that in my example, my menu Item has a property of type ICommand called Command.

Answer (score 6):

[This solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37236/WPF-Menu-using-ViewModel-Part-1) doesn't need any code in code behind and that makes it simpler solution.

```
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildMenuItems}" Header="{Binding Path=Header}">
                <MenuItem.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildMenuItems}">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Header}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SeparatorViewModel}">
                        <Separator>
                            <Separator.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Line X1="0" X2="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Separator.Template>
                        </Separator>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.Resources>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

And MenuItem is represented as:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MenuItemViewModel"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parentViewModel">The parent view model.</param>
        public MenuItemViewModel(MenuItemViewModel parentViewModel)
        {
            ParentViewModel = parentViewModel;
            _childMenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> _childMenuItems;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the child menu items.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The child menu items.</value>
        public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> ChildMenuItems
        {
            get
            {
                return _childMenuItems;
            }
        }

        private string _header;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the header.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The header.</value>
        public string Header
        {
            get
            {
                return _header;
            }
            set
            {
                _header = value; NotifyOnPropertyChanged("Header");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the parent view model.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The parent view model.</value>
        public MenuItemViewModel ParentViewModel { get; set; }

        public virtual void LoadChildMenuItems()
        {

        }
    }
```

The concrete MenuItems can be either instantiated directly or you could make your own SubTypes through inheritance.

Comment: `HierarchicalDataTemplate` inside `MenuItem.Resources` should have a key, otherwise XAML won't compile causing `error MC3022: All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post but I need this plus how to bind Commands.

As to Guge's question on how to bind Commands:
VMMenuItems is a property in my view model class of type

```
ObservableCollection<Menu>
```

and Menu is the class defined above. The MenuItem's Command Property is being bound to the Command Property of the Menu class.
In my view model class

```
Menu.Command = _fou
```

where

```
private ICommand _fou;
```

The xaml

```
<ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VMMenuItems}">
           <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">                                    
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                  </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
      </ContextMenu>                    
</ListView.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering how to do separators it's really quite easy.

The code below is part of my ViewModel. Since XAML uses reflection all I need to do is to return 'object' which can be a `MenuItemViewModel`, `Separator`, or (if for some wierd reason I needed to) an actual `MenuItem`.

I'm using `yield` to dynamically generate the items because it just seems to read better for me. Even though I'm using `yield` - if the items change I still need to raise a `PropertyChanged` event for `"ContextMenu"` as usual but I don't unnecessarily generate the list until it's needed.

```
    public IEnumerable<object> ContextMenu
    {
        get
        {
            // ToArray() needed or else they get garbage collected
            return GetContextMenu().ToArray();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetContextMenu()
    {
        yield return new MenuItemViewModel()
        {
            Text = "Clear all flags",
        };

        // adds a normal 'Separator' menuitem
        yield return new Separator();

        yield return new MenuItemViewModel()
        {
            Text = "High Priority"
        };

        yield return new MenuItemViewModel()
        {
            Text = "Medium Priority"
        };

        yield return new MenuItemViewModel()
        {
            Text = "Low Priority"
        };

        yield break;
    }
```