# How can I get the "Selected MenuItem" in WPF

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

I was wondering how can I get the "Selected" MenuItem from a Menu. 
Basically, I want to get the "Selected" MenuItem so I can sort my ListBox.
Here is my XAML for the Menu.

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Sort by" ItemsSource="{Binding SortByOptions}"
                            *SelectedItem="{Binding GroupBy}"*/>
</Menu>
```

I Switched my ComboBox with a Menu, but in Menu, "SelectedItem" does not exist like in ComboBox. I was wondering how could I get what Item from menu was chosen.

**C#**

The ItemsSource Binding "SortByOptions" is an ObservableCollection of string who contains the options to sort.
The binding "GroupBy" is a String that is set each time the user chose another MenuItem.

I am searching to set the variable "GroupBy" every time the user chose another MenuItem.

Before, my ComboBox worked well.

Comment: [MenuItem.Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.checked.aspx)? You can loop through all the items on your menu and check if this is true for each item. If it is, then the item has been selected.

Comment: Please revise your question to clarify what you mean by selected menu items. Are you trying to put the most recently used commands at the top, or something else?

Comment: It seems to me as if a Menu is a poor substitute for a ComboBox. Could you please provide some more details as to what you are trying to accomplish and why..

Comment: @RogerN I want to be notified every time with the choice of the user from all the choices in Menu.

Comment: @Niclas I am switching from ComboBox to Menu because I was told to do so.

Comment: I think your question is about how to bind commands to dynamically-generated menu items.  There are already a few other similar questions which should help you out.  See Adam Lenda's answer (which is not the 1st one) to this question, [MVVM Dynamic Menu UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392160/mvvm-dynamic-menu-ui-from-binding-with-viewmodel).

Comment: You should answer to your question and validate it ;)

Comment: @GauthierG.Letellier Thank you for specifications. It's done! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I needed to specify the style of the property "Command" and "CommandParameter" like this:

```
<Menu Layout="Text" Margin="10,0,0,0">
  <MenuItem Header="Group by" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupByOptions}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Command"
                Value="{Binding ViewModel.GroupCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Views:MyView}}}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
      </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Note that the CommandParameter is the actual "Header" chosen by the user. (This is what I was searching for) I did not know, but when you do {Binding} it takes the actual string.

And in my ViewModel, here is what it looks like:

```
private ICommand mSortCommand;
//Implement get and set with NotifyPropertyChanged for mSortableList
private ICollectionView mSortableList; 

public ICommand SortCommand
{
  get { return mSortCommand ?? (mSortCommand = new RelayCommand(SortMyList)); } 
}

public void SortMyList(object sortChosen)
{
  string chosenSort = sortChosen as string;
  CampaignSortableList.SortDescriptions.Clear();
  Switch(chosenSort){
    "Sort my List"
  }
  CampaignSortableList.Refresh();
}
```

It works all fine now.