# WPF - MVVM - Dynamic menu creation and Event handling

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I was playing my way through WPF-MVVM and I'm loving it. But seems I'm stuck now.

I dynamically created a menu for my application using the below code:

```
 <Menu x:Name="menuMain" Height="25" Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"/>
```

The menu is displaying fine, but the I don't know how to handle the events raised when each submenu is clicked. Because I am not using any `<MenuItem />` element here in XAML to create the submenus (the submenus are dynamically created) I cannot do that with Commands, neither can I use `EventTriggers`

I am not at all asking how to handle events in MVVM, because I have done it a couple of times. My question basically is if below is my dynamically created menu

```
File
--New
----New Text Document
----New Word Document
--Open
--Add
```

what should I do to handle the event raised when the `New Text Document` menuitem under `New` menuitem which comes under the `File` menu is clicked. Please help me.

Comment: See if [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392160/mvvm-dynamic-menu-ui-from-binding-with-viewmodel) will help.

Comment: You can use the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392160/mvvm-dynamic-menu-ui-from-binding-with-viewmodel?lq=1