# Is it possible to inject a menu into an existing menu in c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I have a simple question, is it possible to inject a whole new menu into an existing menu created in XAML in a c# wpf application so that it looks like this?

```
File(XAML)    Injected Menu(Runtime)    Tools(XAML)
-New          -Task 1                    -Options
-Save         -Task 2
-...
```

Or do I have to build the whole menu with code? Like using `ObservableCollection` for the headers and a `List` or another `ObservableCollection` inside the `ObservableCollection` for the `MenuItems`?

Comment: Can you give me a short hint into the right direction? Is there a way I can hook into the list of MenuItems from a Menu?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392160/mvvm-dynamic-menu-ui-from-binding-with-viewmodel

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, so it is not possible in the way I described my question, I have to create the whole menu from code.

Comment: No, you can create a bindable menu system that generates the menu at runtime from your view model, unless I'm not understanding what you are getting at.

Comment: Yes, I have to create the whole menu at runtime and my question was if I could inject a menu into an existing menu created in XAML, sorry if my question was misleading, can you please post your answer as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Its more of a duplicate than an answer, if you agree its a duplicate or that it solves your problem, I'll vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, It solves my problem, now I know where to start, thanks, sorry for the duplicate then