# How do I dynamically add/remove menu items in my WPF MVVM Telerik application?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I have a WPF application built using the MVVM  pattern. I have a series of top level menus built using Telerik RadMenus within the MVVM pattern.
The menu layout is defined in XMAL.

I would like to be able to dynamically add/remove items (not hide/show) at runtime in the C# code behind.

I assume that I have to alter the menu items in the ViewModel.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to removed them in the code behind when you are using MVVM? Binding their visibility to a property in your ViewModel should do the job.

Comment: Menus are ItemsControls.  You can expose collections of objects which represent operations that can be taken.  Wow, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392160/mvvm-dynamic-menu-ui-from-binding-with-viewmodel amazing what search engines can kick up. Take a peek and see if that fully answers your question.